# Xcode Swift UICollectionView: cellForItemAt IndexPath not called but numberOfItemsInSection does

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am currently programming an app with UICollectionView only when I start the app the CollectionView is not displayed. In my app I do not use the StoryBoard but only the ViewController. That's why I inherit from UICollectionViewController in my app. But when I start the app, the UICollectionView is simply not displayed. Through print commands I found out that the numberOfItemsInSection method is called, but the cellForItemAt indexPath is not. I also know that this will probably be a double question, but I still haven't found a solution for 2 hours. CollectionView.delegateand collectionView.dataSource are both set to = self and there are actually no problems with the constrains because I can turn the background of the UICollectionView to black, for example, and everything is displayed correctly there.
I hope someone can help me.
Best regards

```
// MARK: - Collectionview
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("Item wurde erstellt")
    return messages.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageCollectionViewCell
    
    let message = messages[indexPath.item]
    cell.textView.text = message.message
    
    setUpCell(cell, message)
    cell.bubbleViewWidthAnchor?.constant = estimateFrameForText(text: message.message!).width + 32
    
    print("Celle wird erstellt")
    
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Did you check you inherit `UICollectionViewDataSource`?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer! No I don´t inherit UICollectionViewDataSource. But even if I try to inherit it, I get an error: `Redundant conformance of 'ChatController' to protocol 'UICollectionViewDataSource'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed the height and width for the cell. You should also check the message array count,  perhaps it is zero.

```
extension YouClass: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return messages.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageCollectionViewCell
    
    let message = messages[indexPath.item]
    cell.textView.text = message.message
    
    setUpCell(cell, message)
    cell.bubbleViewWidthAnchor?.constant = estimateFrameForText(text: message.message!).width + 32
    
    print("Celle wird erstellt")
    
    return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collBanner.frame.width, height: 140)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I have already specified the height and width. In addition, the message array is not empty for me either. I could see that through a print ... In addition, the cellForItemAt indexPath method is not called if I simply return for example 10 with the numberOfItemsInSection method